# FFMPEG: How to record video from one source and audio from other source?

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, ip

I'm using this command to record camera ip:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.105/media/video1 -c:a aac -c:v copy -flags +global_header -strftime 1 -f segment -map 0:0 -segment_time 30 -reset_timestamps 1 file_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

But i would like to add an audio from a different camera ip which use this stream rtsp://192.168.1.106/media/video1

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Use

```
ffmpeg
     -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.105/media/video1
     -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.106/media/video1
     -c:a aac -c:v copy ...
```

If both the inputs have audio, you should map to make sure the correct inputs are chosen, by adding `-map 0:v -map 1:a`.

Comment: Okey got it working, audio is recorded from another source but my video fps just dropped badly, any ideas?

Comment: If your 2nd source provides timestamps, drop the wallclock source for it.